# How can I stop Mui DatePicker clear action from closing the modal

Tags: material-ui

I am using @mui/x-date-pickers, Is there a way to stop the clear action from closing the modal?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

function DateRangePicker() {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(null);
    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <DatePicker
                closeOnSelect={false}
                onChange={(date) => {
                    setDate(date);
                }}
                slotProps={{
                    actionBar: {
                        actions: ["clear"],
                    },
                }}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    );
}

export default DateRangePicker;
```

I can't seem to see any props that controls that.
[The documentation on the clear action](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/#action-bar) states: “Reset to the empty value and close the picker view.”

Answer (score 0):

Try using Event handler. Maintain a state value, and use it for **open** prop of `DatePicker` and updated the open's value according to your need, like if user clicks outside the `DatePicker`, `setOpen(false)`, if user clicks on `DatePicker setOpen(true)`.

Answer (score -2):

You can prevent the Mui DatePicker clear action from closing the modal by passing a custom function to the onAccept prop of the DatePicker component that checks whether the input value is empty or not. If the input value is empty, the function should return false to prevent the modal from closing, and if the input value is not empty, the function should return true to allow the modal to close.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, it didn't even get fired when I hit clear
in the docs it says
"Callback fired when the value is accepted.

Signature:
function(value: TValue) => void
value: The value that was just accepted."

it doesn't look like it should return a value???

Comment: I've also tried to use
open, onOpen and onClose
but I want the user to be able to close the modal by clicking outside
so the normal onClose flow should work except when clicking clear